# Fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04, but extremely laggy

Tags: graphics, 22.04, intel-graphics

I've just installed Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 on a Supermicro X12SCA-F, Xeon W-1250, 32GB ECC, 250 GB SSD 970 EVO Plus. The CPU has an Intel UHD Graphics P630.
I've installed Ubuntu Studio on it and it was working snappy without issues.
I did a fresh install of Ubuntu Desktop and chose ZFS as the file system. I also chose the minimal install.

But it's extremely laggy. I can barely use the system. typing and moving the mouse is extremely laggy.
Anyone know what might cause this problem?

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
*-display

   description: VGA compatible controller product: ASPEED Graphics Family vendor: ASPEED 
   Technology, Inc. bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0 logical name: /dev/fbo width: 32 bits
   physical id: 0
   version: 41
   clock: 33MHZ
   capabilities: pm msi vga_controller cap_list rom fb configuration: depth=32 driver=ast 
   latency=0 resolution=1920, 1080 resources: irq:19 memory: a1000000-a1ffffff memory: 
   a2000000-a201ffff topor
   t:3000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: A similar thing happened to me too. Switching to Wayland solved the problem. You may try it as a workaround:
https://itsfoss.com/switch-xorg-wayland/